# Why tab in strings displayed different?

Tags: go

When using below codes to print msg to a file.

```
fmt.Fprintln(FileWriter, "1.0|8.0\tb,a\t3,1,1")
fmt.Fprintln(FileWriter, "a\tb\tc")
```

why the tab is different?

```
1.0|8.0 b,a 3,1,1
a   b   c
```

Comment: "different" to _what_? It's up to the viewer application on how to interpret `\t` character.

Comment: I get the output you showed when I my terminal tabs are set to every 4 spaces. Check your setup, whatever it is. Also verify the file contents with a hex dump if you must.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in how the tabs are displayed in both lines.

Tabs are rendered as a whitespace that extends up to the next column number that is a multiple of the tab width, in this case 4. In other words, the whitespace always ends in column 4, 8, 12, 16, etc.

```
column: 12345678901234567
line 1: 1.0|8.0 b,a 3,1,1
line 2: a   b   c
```